# Osclass dropdown for category

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, categories, osclass

I have a problemme with osclass

I have a select dropdown for category in Osclass (search.php)

when i select category the attribut don't change only when i click applay (Submiy bouton)

Exemple i search fo a car and i have the attribut to choose make, model,....

if i change the select to exemple dating, i still have the attribut for car, i have allaways to clic applay for the attribu change

in the item-post.php it's good we just select and the attribut change

I want the same function for the search.php

my code for search.php

```
<div class="row">
```

Please somebody helpme, just the function to have he attribu i thik t the search_form) when i just change the selction please please 
My theme is (Spain)

Thank you
Sandra

Answer (score 0):

My code is for sapin theme `<div class="row">

<?php osc_categories_select('sCategory', $category, __('Select a category', 'spain')) ; ?>
</div>`